# What the code type of this string and how to decode it?

Tags: go, unicode, utf-8

Sorry if it's a stupid question or I didn't give enough information. I have a string which should represent an ID: `"\x8f\x04.\x8b8\x8e\nP\xbd\xe3\vLf\xd6W*\x92vb\x8b2"`, and I'm confused on what it is? I try to decode it with utf-8, utf-16, and gbk but none of them works. I realized the `\x` means hexadecimal, but what is `\v` and `\nP`?

Answer (score 1):

The text in the question looks like binary data encoded to a Go interpreted [string literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals).  Use [strconv.Unquote](https://godoc.org/strconv#Unquote) to convert the text back to binary data:

```
s, err := strconv.Unquote(`"\x8f\x04.\x8b8\x8e\nP\xbd\xe3\vLf\xd6W*\x92vb\x8b2"`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%x\n", s) // prints 8f042e8b388e0a50bde30b4c66d6572a9276628b32
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s) // prints "\x8f\x04.\x8b8\x8e\nP\xbd\xe3\vLf\xd6W*\x92vb\x8b2"
```

The [Go language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) defines the syntax. The `\n` represents a byte with the value 10. The `\v` represents a byte with the value 11.  The `\xXX` is hexadecimal as noted in the question.